# Create one alias virtual colum containing value of either of two columns

Tags: mysql

See the SQL query below:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
    (SELECT 
         h.hotel_id AS id,h.hotel_city AS city,h.hotel_name AS hotelname,
         h.hotel_star AS hotelcat, hwd.double_spl_rate, hwd.third_party_rate,
         hwd.extra_bed_spl_rate, hwd.meal_plan_spl,
         hwd.third_party_extra_bed, hwd.third_party_meal_plan,
         hwd.room_category, hrd.hotel_rate_from, hrd.hotel_rate_to 
     FROM 
         hotels_list AS h 
     INNER JOIN 
         hotel_rate_detail AS hrd ON h.hotel_id = hrd.hotels_id
     INNER JOIN 
         hotel_week_days AS hwd ON hrd.hotel_id = hwd.h_id
     WHERE 
         (('2015-07-31' BETWEEN hrd.hotel_rate_from AND hrd.hotel_rate_to)
          OR 
          ('2015-08-01' BETWEEN hrd.hotel_rate_from AND hrd.hotel_rate_to)
         )
         AND (h.hotel_city = '1')
         AND (hwd.double_spl_rate != 0 OR hwd.third_party_rate != 0)
         AND (h.hotel_star = '4')
     ORDER BY 
         hwd.double_spl_rate, hwd.third_party_rate ASC) AS result_table 
GROUP BY 
    result_table.id
ORDER BY 
    result_table.double_spl_rate, result_table.third_party_rate ASC
LIMIT 0,5;
```

OUTPUT is attached below:

[image]

In the above output there are two columns `double_spl_rate` and `third_party_rate` which can be either 0 or a value greater than zero.

How can I create a virtual column alias which only contain values greater the zero. Let us suppose the column is `final_rate` which will contain values as

```
id   | final_rate
533  |   3776
9228 |   3000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this like so:

```
select 
  id, 
  case 
    when coalesce(double_spl_rate,0) = 0 
    then third_party_rate 
    else double_spl_rate 
  end as final_rate
from table
```

The `coalesce` operator will set `double_spl_rate` to 0 if it's null, and the case expression will return `third_party_rate` if `double_spl_rate` is 0.

If `double_spl_rate` cannot be null you can skip the `coalesce` part.

Note that the code above will always prefer the value in `double_spl_rate` and disregard the other value if both values are greater than 0. If you don't want this you could extend the logic in the case expression to account for that and return the sum of the values instead. Or you could simply just return `third_party_rate + double_spl_rate` in all cases.